# Restrict the access for some resource ( URL1) only from SERVER1

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, tomcat7

I'm not sure it's the right approach...I'm working with Spring, Tomcat7, Linux
On my Linux Server I've a firewall, with these rules

Port 8081 is open only to SERVER1
Port 8443 is open to all IPs

i want to restrict the access for some resource ( URL1) only from SERVER1.
But users might try to access URL1 via port 8443, i don't want that.
how can i restrict the access to URL1 only to SERVER1. i thought to check if the request arrives on port 8443 not 8081. reject it

can this be done and how?

---

```
Ok. i found out i could use: org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter
I've added this filter to my "web.xml" file. which means: restrict requests only on port 8081...but now i always get: 
"Access to the specified resource has been forbidden"

What i'm i missing?


<filter>
        <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allow</param-name>
            <param-value>((\d{1,3}(-\d{1,3})?|x)\.){3}(\d{1,3}(-\d{1,3})?|x):8081</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/snabel/myService</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Thanks,
Snabel

Comment: can u show your server_config.xml code